# SublimeText keeps inserting \xc2 characters

Tags: sublimetext2

I use SublimeText for writing Python. Every so often it will insert characters that I didn't type. Today's example:

> Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file
>   /path/to/my/project/forms.py on line 256, but no encoding
>   declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
>   (forms.py, line 256)

This doesn't happen to my colleagues and happens to me from time to time. I'm not sure what to do about it. I can delete the line and re-type it and it's fine. I have tried updating versions etc etc.

I don't want to just set the file encoding because I'm not actually typing non-ascii characters and that would be ignoring the actual problem.

Has anyone else found this? Solutions?

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding issue between your platform and theirs. I never have this issue unless i transfer something from a UTF-8 *Nix machine to my Windows machine where it assumes latin-1 because that's what the file was saved as when trasnfering over but the actual encoding within the document is still UTF-8.
Try: "Reppen with encoding" to <your encoding of choice> (it's in the menues). If that works then you have the same issue as me most likely.

Comment: tell me - open `Preferences->Settings - User`  do you have the `default_encoding` key?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I don't have a `default_encoding`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that looking at the characters I'm typing, it would come out the same as UTF-8 and ASCII though.

Comment: @Torxed - I'm only doing this on my machine, although I'm running the code in a Linux VM. Shouldn't make a difference though, surely?

Comment: (Also I fixed this so I can't replicate it until it happens again, which is intermittently. That's why I think it's a bug)

Comment: It makes a difference depending on your transfer method. I use SCP but from windows it will re-encode the document to a specific configuration, this is where things can go wrong obviously. I still think you're on the path of transfer error rather than a bug (I use Sublime myself and many others and non of them have ghost encoding issues, many of us have bumped in to transfer encoding issues tho which is noticed when opening the files)

Comment: Trust me, I am nowhere near Windows! I'm using Vagrant, which mounts a node of the host filesystem into the guest filesystem, I'm not sure how. It's entirely possible that it's transport, but I would be very surprised if it doesn't map the files at block level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens to me too! If you are in MacOS you´re typing ⌥ + space, if you are windows/Linux I guess it's alt + space

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/whats-altspacebar-character-and-how-to-disable-it

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Actually I don't need to deactivate it because, it happened to me when I was using a spanish keyboard, since you need ⌥ to type characters like {}[]. And you end up making the mistake to press ⌥ + space. Now I'm using an english keyboard for programming :). Anyway thanks for the link!

Comment: Wow. That could be it. It's not very likely, but it's the most likely thing so far, and it has the same effect. I'll keep a look out.

Comment: This is basically the only char you could add and not notice that you added. Happens a lot to fast typists... :-) Especially troublesome in (programming) languages that use chars that need Alt.

Comment: Any way to prevent Sublime from doing this, like set that chat to space once it has been (accidentally) inserted?