# Error with converting a string negative number to an integer when importing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-from-csv

My Ruby environment is: Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0.1.

I'm trying to convert a negative string number in an integer, for instance:

When I try to turn this "-2000" in the *irb* terminal, I got the result expected *-2000*

But I'm trying to convert this when I import this data from a *CSV* file.

I'm using the following information:

CSV file

```
345,­-2000
345,120000
```

Code file

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv") do |row|
  p [row[0], row[1]]
  p row[1].to_i
  p row[1].force_encoding('UTF-8').to_i
  p Integer(row[1])
  p Integer(row[1].force_encoding('UTF-8'))
end
```

I got that:

```
["345", "­-2000"]
0
0
'Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "\xC2\xAD2000" (ArgumentError)
'Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "\xC2\xAD2000" (ArgumentError)
```

Using the Integer(), I discovered that the - sign is represented by "\xC2\xAD".

In summary, the to_i method is converting "\xC2\xAD2000" to 0 and the Integer() is trigging an error.

Could someone help with that?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Where did this data come from and/or what is the CSV encoded as? This tutorial might help - http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/

Comment: @DamienRoche this is a simple file with CSV extension. I did not encode this file. I just use the CSV class to turn each row in a line in an array and. I will see the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: `force_encoding` should only be used in very specific cases; and almost never when opening a file (unless you know there's specific text that doesn't conform to the overall encoding of the file). Instead you should specify the encoding when opening the CSV; see [the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually have two characters here..

- `\xC2`: [SublimeText keeps inserting \xc2 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382834/sublimetext-keeps-inserting-xc2-characters)
- `\xAD`: (soft-hyphen) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm

Personally, I would replace this combination of characters with an actual hyphen and then convert to integer:

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv") do |row|
  p row[1].sub("\xC2\xAD", '-').to_i
end
```

That, or clean up the source file. Unsure of how you are generating it, but worth looking into.